# CVX program for the matrix variable optimization

Tags: matlab, convex-optimization, cvx

This question is about solving the problem on CVX using MATLAB:

[image]

My variable is W which is a N X N matrix. a is n X 1 vector. Sigma is a PSD matrix.

a) Can I solve this problem in Disciplined manner?
b) How to reformulate this in cvx since CVX says the Quadratic forms need to be with scalars. (equalities are matrix equalities).

Comment: No, cvx will not address this as it is nonconvex.

Comment: Why is it non-convex? I am sorry but having a matrix variable confuses me The objective is quadratic in entries of W, and so are the constraints..then why is this non convex? And how should I try solving this  problem?

Comment: Take the trivial scalar case, and think of the feasible points of the scalar quadratic constraint w^2=1

Comment: Yeah Got it. w^2 = 1, w = +/- 1  -> feasible region is non convex. same is true if sigma is I. Thnks.

Comment: How do I then solve this problem? Newton's method?

Comment: Local method (using Newton etc), or a global approach using spatial branch-and-bound or semidefinite relaxations. However, the problem is strange, as the second equation yields $W^{-1}=W^T$ which when you plug into the first $\Sigma W^T = W^T$ which only can be solved when $\Sigma = I$